# Setting a property in grunt is creating an unwanted json object

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to set a property in grunt with the command `grunt.config(<property>, <value>)` and grunt will not escape a period `.` that is in my property name, and turns it into a new json object.  I am looping through a list of projects and creating a list of less files.  Here is the code.

```
grunt.config('projects').forEach(function(project) {
  grunt.config('less.development.files.' + project + '.less', 'project/' + project + '.css');
});
```

I want the result to be a json object with a less key and a css value like this `project.less : project.css`.

This gives me a json object that looks like this

```
{
  "file1": {
    "less": "project\/file1.css"
  },
  "file2": {
    "less": "project\/file2.css"
  },
  "file3": {
    "less": "project\/file3.css"
  }
}
```

If I change the filenames from `.less` to `_less`, then the object looks like I want.

```
{
  "file1_less": "project\/file1.css",
  "file2_less": "project\/file2.css",
  "file3_less": "project\/file3.css",
}
```

but I want it to be `.less`.  What do I do to make Grunt not create this as a new object?  I have tried double quotes, single quotes, single quotes with escaping, and pushing the key/value into a variable name and using the variables.  None of these worked.  Does anyone have any other ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the end goal of this configuration? Is there not a simpler way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grunt.config('projects').forEach(function(project) {
  grunt.config.data.less.development.files[project + '.less'] = 'project/' + project + '.css';
});
```

Basically, you want to use that concatenated string with the .less as the key so you can access it directly through the `grunt.config.data.less.development.files` object using square bracket notation.

That assumes you already have a placeholder for it like:

```
grunt.config.init({
  less:{
    development:{
      files:[]
    }
  }
})
```